# Alamofire HTTP Request

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

i want to send http post request with Alamofire. there is my code for send request in sampleViewController and get response from request. there is a problem i got response from server but when I want to print response in sample view controller my response always return nil. how can check response after get response from server?

```
  public class PersistencyManager {

 func SendPostHttpRequest(baseURL: String, parameter: [String:Any?], content: String) -> Any? {

        let url = URL(string: Constant.baseURL)
     var result : Any?

        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)
          urlRequest.setValue("text/html; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
          urlRequest.setURLEncodedFormData(parameters: parameter)

          Alamofire.request(urlRequest).responseJSON { response in

            switch response.result {

            case .success :


              if let JSON = response.result.value as? [String:Any] {
                print("JSON: \(JSON)")

                result = JSON
              }



            case .failure :

              result = nil

            }
          }
        default:
          break
        }

        return result

    }
    }


    class sampleViewController: UIViewController {

      @IBOutlet weak var sendButton: UIButton!
      @IBOutlet weak var centerVIew: UIView!
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()



      }

     @IBAction func SendRequest(_ sender: Any) {

        let parameters = ["key":Constant.serverKey,"userid":"0" ,"action":"vitrin","step":"list","sort": nil,"filter":nil,"start":String("5"),"end":String("8")]

        Constant.libraryAPI.parameters = parameters
        Constant.libraryAPI.requestContent = "String"



          let response = Constant.libraryAPI.GetAPIResponse(parameters: parameters, contentType: "String")
         print(response) //this line call before get response from server
     }
    }
```

Comment: Alamofire requests async. That means your `SendPostHttpRequest` returns  immediately.

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov How can handle response in another controller ?

Comment: You should pass closure to `SendPostHttpRequest` which should be called when response is delivered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a closure but calling the closure in the callback of Alamofire when is success or failed, then you can check if `error` in your closure is nil, then all os ok and you can use the `JSON`

```
   func SendPostHttpRequest(baseURL: String, parameter: [String:Any?], content: String, closure:@escaping ((_ success:JSON?,_ error:NSError?) -> Void)) {

    let url = URL(string: Constant.baseURL)
    var result : Any?

    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)
    urlRequest.setValue("text/html; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    urlRequest.setURLEncodedFormData(parameters: parameter)

    Alamofire.request(urlRequest).responseJSON { response in

        switch response.result {

        case .success :

            if let JSON = response.result.value as? [String:Any] {
                print("JSON: \(JSON)")

                closure(JSON,nil)
            }else{
                closure(nil,NSError(domain: "Error in JSON parsing", code: 995, userInfo: nil))
            }

        case .failure :
            closure(nil,response.result.error)
        }

    }

}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

As @Orkhan said, your `SendPostHttpRequest` returns immediately. You should closure. Try this:

```
public class PersistencyManager {
func SendPostHttpRequest(baseURL: String, parameter: [String:Any?], content: String, withCompletionBlock completion:(@escaping(Any?) -> Swift.Void)?) {

        let url = URL(string: Constant.baseURL)
        var result : Any?

        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)
        urlRequest.setValue("text/html; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        urlRequest.setURLEncodedFormData(parameters: parameter)

        Alamofire.request(urlRequest).responseJSON { response in

            switch response.result {

            case .success :


                if let JSON = response.result.value as? [String:Any] {
                    print("JSON: \(JSON)")

                    result = JSON
                }



            case .failure :

                result = nil

            }
        }
        default:
        break

         completion?(result)
    }

    }
}
```

Comment: @NaGib ToroNgo , thanks for reply, i try your code but get this error :  'default' label can only appear inside a 'switch' statement

Comment: it could be mismatch in brackets @ava. Check the brackets. I didn't run it. If you still fetch problem please comment here....i'll fix

Comment: @NaGib ToroNgo  when add default in switch statement , agin  first call this method   print(response) //this line call before get response from server and print optional(())
and then get response

Comment: @NaGib ToroNgo i update my answer for that you can see my changes code , if your answer is helpful i should vote that.

Comment: @NaGibToroNgo your answer is wrong because you are calling the closure before the Alamofire callback returns, this is essentially the same behaviour as return way only difference is the closure